Counting Non-blanks and Date Condition within Specific Ranges
I'm trying to make this work with when I filter data on excel I understand countif doesn't work here but I can't seem to make SUBTOTAL work.
=((SUBTOTAL(103,A3:A76))-(COUNTIF(E3:E76,"<="&(TODAY()-365))+COUNTIF(E3:E76,"")))/SUBTOTAL(103,A3:A76)

I was expecting it to filter data at first but it didn't
Then I tried this but I wasn't able to make it work
=((SUBTOTAL(103, A3:A76)) - (SUBTOTAL(109, E3:E76 * (E3:E76 <= TODAY() - 365)) + SUBTOTAL(109, E3:E76 = ""))) / SUBTOTAL(103, A3:A76)


To consider the visible ones after filtering, we need to use SUBTOTAL etc. as you have done. So SUBTOTAL(103, cell) will be 1 (and thus TRUE) if the cell is visible and not blank.
If you have Microsoft 365, could you try entering this where you need the result:
=LET(
    col_a, A3:A76,
    col_e, E3:E76,
    is_visible_and_not_blank, LAMBDA(cell, SUBTOTAL(103, cell)),
    older_than_a_year_in_e, REDUCE(
        0,
        col_e,
        LAMBDA(count, e_,
            count +
                IF(
                    AND(
                        is_visible_and_not_blank(e_),
                        e_ <= (TODAY() - 365)
                    ),
                    1,
                    0
                )
        )
    ),
    non_blanks_in_a, SUBTOTAL(103, col_a),
    result, (non_blanks_in_a - older_than_a_year_in_e) /
        non_blanks_in_a,
    result
)

